# Jupyter lab cannot connect to a kernel of a pipenv environment

Tags: jupyter-lab, pipenv

I have python 3.8.5 installed with conda (miniconda). Jupyter lab is installed in the 'base' environment. I created a project and its virtual environment (fibonacci-6zMY4jHo) with 'pipenv'. To add the fibonacci-6zMY4jHo as a kernel into Jupyter lab, I did the following:

1. activated fibonacci-6zMY4jHo:

   ```
   pipenv shell
   ```
2. installed ipykernel:

   ```
   pipenv install ipykernel
   ```
3. Added fibonacci-6zMY4jHo to jupyter lab:

   ```
   ipython kernel install --user --name=fibonacci-6zMY4jHo
   ```

Next:I run jupyter lab from the base environmnet. The list of kernels shows fibonacci-6zMY4jHo, but when I select it, jupter is not able to connect to it.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, I created a virtual env with pipenv, added into jupyter as shown above, the env. Id successfully added to kernels list in jupyter. When i select the env. ftom the kernel lists in jupyter lab, jupyter cannot connect to it. I want to know why and how to troubleshoot this issue.